# Word VBA Printing the whole document

Tags: vba, printing, ms-word

Currently Sub CurrentpageP() is only printing the first page of the document.

Can't figure out a way of making it print the whole document. I have changed the pages parameters to the following but no luck "1-9999" and "1-2".

[Link here](http://www.henryedwards.co.uk/macros.txt) for the long code - below is the snippet the of section.

```
Sub CurrentpageP()
With ActiveDocument.PageSetup
    .FirstPageTray = 281
    .OtherPagesTray = 281
End With
Application.PrintOut FileName:="", Range:=wdPrintCurrentPage, Item:= _
    wdPrintDocumentContent, Copies:=1, pages:="", PageType:=wdPrintAllPages, _
    Collate:=True, Background:=True, PrintToFile:=False, PrintZoomColumn:=0, _
    PrintZoomRow:=0, PrintZoomPaperWidth:=0, PrintZoomPaperHeight:=0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the Range to "**wdPrintCurrentPage**", your telling Word to only print the current page.  If you want to print the whole document, you need to set the Range to "**wdPrintAllDocument**".  The Range types are listed here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb237956(v=office.12).aspx